# Send Performance - Delivery Rate (WarmUp)

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, email-studio, email-tracking, ip-warming

Our costumer are passing by email WarmUp and i did some email send, but the most of our send have been blocked by high rates block bounces, as you can see on the image below:

[image]
[image]

The email content was made by HTML script with text and images, we don´t know if the block bounces (bounce reason: Content) are occouring because of the text.

The lead data-base is not big, and i'd like know if one else has already passed by similar situation to help to minimize the block bounces.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.